# Make post title active

Tags: php, wp-get-archives

Hi I have a simple website that displays every post title in a list, I'm trying to change the active post title to be different when its being viewed. I have tried this but it's not working.

```
<ul class="students">
 <?php

 $IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
 global $post;

 $myposts = wp_get_archives('type=alpha');
 foreach($myposts as $post) :
 ?>

      <li <?php if(is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID) print 'style="font-weight:bold";' 
      ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code relies on time travel to work:

```
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
global $post;
```

Specifically the first line is peering into the future, how can it know what `$post->ID` is if it's undeclared? The fix is `global $post;`, but when the computer gets to that line, it's too late

```
global $post;
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
```

If you want to list posts, you should consider `WP_Query` or `get_posts`. It may be faster in your case to use `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 0):

These lines are superfluous:

```
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
global $post;
```

You don't need them. Try just `var_dump($post->ID);` and you will see that the variable is already available.

Now, from the Codex:

> This function **displays** a date-based archives list. This tag can be
>   used anywhere within a template.

By default, `wp_list_archives()` echoes content. Your `$myposts` variable isn't set. Altering your code like this...

```
$args = array(
  'type' => 'alpha',
  'echo' => false,
);
$myposts = wp_get_archives($args);
```

... will fix that problem, but you get a string, not an array that you can iterate over. And, `wp_get_archives()` already generates an HTML list by default.

Sadly, the filters available for manipulating the output are frustratingly limited. You'd need to get into dicey `regex` on markup, and the pattern would change with permalink structure, or you could do a resource intensive search for posts based on the url:

```
function alter_list_output_wpse_190357($link) {
  global $post;

  $pat = "|(<li[^>]*>).* href='([^']*)'(.*>)|";
  preg_match($pat,$link,$matches);
  $id = url_to_postid($matches[2]);
  if ($post->ID === $id) {
    $link = preg_replace($pat,"<li style=\"font-weight:bold\"><a href='$2' $3",$link);
  }
  return $link;
}
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'alter_list_output_wpse_190357' );
```

You are probably better off using `WP_Query` or `get_posts` as already suggested in an answer by Tom J Nowell, but I wanted to explain the project.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the end that worked

```
<?php

global $post;
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 999, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>

   <li <?php if(is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID) print 'class="viewing"'; ?>>     
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```